# Tail latest file that matches a selected rule

Tags: linux, bash

Have a directory that multiple processes log to and I want to tail the latest file of a selected process.

in ~/bashrc I have added the following

```
function __taillog {

        tail -f $(find $1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n | tail -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f 2-)
}

alias taillog='__taillog'
```

Taken from: https://superuser.com/questions/117596/how-to-tail-the-latest-file-in-a-directory

An example of the log file directory

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 genesys genesys   2284 Mar 19 16:34 gdalog.20130319_163436_906.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 genesys genesys 131072 Mar 19 16:34 gdalog.20130319_163436_906.snapshot.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 genesys genesys  10517 Mar 19 16:54 lcalog.20130319_163332_719.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 genesys genesys 131072 Mar 19 16:54 lcalog.20130319_163332_719.snapshot.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 genesys genesys   3792 Mar 19 16:37 StatServer_TLSTest.20130319_163700_703.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 genesys genesys 160562 Mar 19 16:52 StatServer_TLSTest.20130319_163712_045.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 genesys genesys  49730 Mar 19 16:54 StatServer_TLSTest.20130319_165217_402.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 genesys genesys  53960 Mar 20 09:55 StatServer_TLSTest.20130319_165423_702.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 genesys genesys 131072 Mar 20 09:56 StatServer_TLSTest.20130319_165423_702.snapshot.log
```

So to tail the all StatServer the command would be

```
taillog /home/user/logs/StatServer*
```

and it would tail the latest file for that application in the given path

**The issue is** the tail displays some of the file output but does not show any updates when the log file is appended. If the following command is run the log is tailed correctly

```
tail -f $(find /home/user/logs/StatServer*  -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n | tail -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f 2-)
```

Some how adding this command as a bash function then calling it from an alias causes it to not operate as desired.

Any suggestion on a better way are welcome.

Comment: Is it working? What is the problem?

Comment: Also, your find chain seems fairly complicated, I'd just use ls -t for this.

Comment: The tail does display a segment of the log file but it does not update when the log file is appended by the application.

Comment: Does running `tail -f filename` work with the same log file when you append stuff to it ? Because I do not see anything the command does special other than determine and pass the log file argument to `tail -f`. Also remember that your command will `tail` only the log file which was latest when you invoked the command and does not dynamically output lines from different log files as they're updated.

Comment: yes, the tail -f filename works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be running this command:

```
taillog /home/user/logs
```

When you say `/home/user/logs/this_app*` you're passing all the files that match the pattern as argument to `taillog` and only using the first argument i.e. `$1`, and the command eventually translates to `tail -f $1`.

Instead `$1` should be the directory where `find` should look for the files at that directory level (i.e. `/home/user/logs` in your case), then pipe the results to `sort`, `tail` and `cut`.

Comment: I have added more information to the question as a result of your answer, dont think the question was clear enough (sorry). As a result your answer did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any problems running your taillog function on linux/bash.  Perhaps the log output is being buffered, so changes aren't being written right away?  You might try turning off the [log]buffering option for this StatServer.